# PDFBox changes font name from language character to english character

Tags: pdfbox

While merging 2 pdf with pdfbox / opening pdf in pdfbox debugger, if PDF file have font name with language character like MSゴシック or MS明朝, then it changes font to ",l,rfsfvfbfn" or ",l,r-3/4c"

If we have pdf with font "MS Gothic" in english, it merges document properly.

Changing font name leads to spacing issue in merged document and makes it unreadable as few characters overlaps.

Difference in font while open in PDFDebugger
[image]

Difference in font after merging
[image]

Comment: What PDFBox version are you using? The latest is 2.0.27.

Comment: I checked with pdfbox-app-2.0.27.jar and pdfbox-app-3.0.0-alpha3.jar, both version have same issue.

Comment: Then it's a bug and you should create an issue in JIRA. (This is complicated if you don't have an account there because of spammers; see https://infra.apache.org/jira-guidelines.html ). We'll need the file.

Comment: Thanks Tilman, I will raise JIRA with sample pdf file.